# Turkish characters problem while plotting graphs in R igraph

Tags: r, plot, igraph, tm

I have a dataset which includes Tweets in Turkish language. I'm trying to do text mining with tm package and plot the networks with igraph R packages.

```
    library(tm)
#build corpus
corpus <- iconv(deneme$text, to= "utf-8-mac")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpus))
removeURL <- function(x) gsub('http[[:alnum:]]*', '', x)
cleanset <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
cleanset <- tm_map(cleanset, stripWhitespace)
#term document matrix
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(cleanset)
tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)
tdm <- tdm[rowSums(tdm)>30,]
tdm[tdm>1] <- 1
termM <- tdm %*% t(tdm)
#Network
g <- graph.adjacency(termM, weighted = T, mode = 'undirected') 
g <- simplify(g)
V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)
#plot
plot(g,
     vertex.color='green',
     vertex.size = 3,
     vertex.label.dist = 1.5)
```

[Output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynH59.jpg)

Turkish charachters such as "ş ğ ü" do not appear correctly. What might be the problem?

and this is my R studio locale settings:

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Could you inform the version of {igraph} package you are using? I'm using igraph v1.2.11, and I got an error when I tried to do indexing by using `V(g)$label`-like syntax. In addition, I don't find `graph.adjacency()`. It's likely that this version has replaced it with `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`.

Comment: ‘igraph’ version 1.2.6

Comment: Unfortunately, I failed to install v1.2.6 from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph/ because `glpk.h` is not found. I have no other suggestion than using Unicode  hex directly : `paste("\U015F", "\U011F", "\U00FC")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the package, rerun the code with the new command `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()` without a problem . The final output of the plot is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to apply `iconv()` function to `ş,ğ,ü` characters by using all available encodings in `iconvlist()`, but nothing can print these characters perfectly on the R console and on the plot. I did that by using this code:

```
encoded_text <- list()
for (i in seq_along(iconvlist())) {
  tryCatch(print(eval(substitute(
    encoded_text[[i]] <- unlist(lapply(c("s", "g", "ü"), iconv,
      to = iconvlist()[i]
    ))
  ))),
  error = function(any_error_msg) message(as.character(any_error_msg))
  )
}

#To show all the results: 
encoded_text
```

I also tried `utf8_print("ş,ğ,ü")` from `utf-8` package, but also failed.

Finally, I found `readtext` package. This package can print these character properly on the console and on the plot in my computer. However, the current version of this package (v0.81) can only read a file, not a character vector. So, to use this package, I typed these characters in the Notepad, separated by commas, and then I saved the file with `.txt` extension.

[image]

Then, I used this code to extract these characters:

```
library(readtext)
mytext <- readtext('turkish_text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8')
mytext <- unlist(strsplit(mytext$text, ","))
mytext
#[1] "ş" "ğ" "ü"
```

They are properly printed on the console. Then, I tried to print them on the plot of an igraph object.

```
adjm <- matrix(1:9, nc=3)
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix( adjm )
g1 <- g1 %>% set_vertex_attr("name", value = mytext)
plot(g1)
```

Here is the resulted plot:

[image]

The characters are properly printed on the plot.

Of course no guarantee that this approach will be applicable to other Turkish characters, but I think it's worthy to try.