# Special Characters Issue in R 4.3.2

Tags: r, utf-8

I'm having trouble with special characters.

It worked:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, main = "Main Title")
```

It doesn't work:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y, main = "Main Tütle")
```

`Error: unexpected symbol`
Plus, I can not knit, I can not run basic Shiny codes. So on. I can't even save a basic plot to my desktop (File path name has also special characters).

R Version: 4.3.2

Windows language: Turkish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turkish characters problem while plotting graphs in R igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781885/turkish-characters-problem-while-plotting-graphs-in-r-igraph)

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't.